# How to add a select system date statement in the where clause

Tags: sql, oracle

Need help. I try to add a select clause in where clause in my query so that it can select the data which is same as the device system date .

> my code that work:
> `(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM W.BrwDate) = '2021')`

I try to add `select sysdate from dual;` so no need to write the specific year and query can be use for every year . But if i combine the code it no work

`WHERE (EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RegYear = (select sysdate extract (year from dual))))`

So is that any method can solve my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be

```
where extract (year from regyear) = extract (year from sysdate)
```

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot, it work, i am so dumb to add a select into it

Comment: You're not; you're just *new*.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late, but you have this alternative also

```
WHERE TRUNC(RegYear,'YYYY') = TRUNC(SYSDATE,'YYYY')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range comparison:

```sql
WHERE RegYear >= TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY')
AND   RegYear <  ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY'), 12)
```

This does not apply a function to your column values (only applying functions on `SYSDATE`) and will allow Oracle to use an index on the `RegYear` column.

---

If you compare for equality of the years using:

```sql
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RegYear) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
```

or equality of truncated dates:

```sql
WHERE TRUNC(RegYear, 'YY') = TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'YY')
```

Then Oracle will have to apply the function to every value in the column and will not use an index on `RegYear`. Instead, to use an index, you would need a separate function-based index on `EXTRACT(YEAR FROM RegYear)` or `TRUNC(RegYear, 'YY')` respectively.